# Set parameters in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, parameter-passing, sql-server-2014, reportviewer

I want my report to display all the products that have the stock less than the value that's inserted in the **Search** text box. There is error.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryReport]
    @Stock int
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Product
    WHERE Stock < @Stock
    ORDER BY Stock ASC
```

This is the code when user enter value in **Search** text box.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtbl = GetInventoryReport_Result();

    rptInventoryStock.Visible = true;
    rptInventoryStock.LocalReport.ReportPath = "InventoryReport.rdlc";
    rptInventoryStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    rptInventoryStock.LocalReport.Add(new ReportDataSource("IOOP_DatabaseDataSet", dtbl));

    this.rptInventoryStock.RefreshReport();
}
```

This is the function for `GetInventoryReport_Result()`:

```
private DataTable GetInventoryReport_Result()
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("GetInventoryReport", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", txtSearch.Text.Trim());

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlCon != null)
            sqlCon.Close();
    }

    return dtbl;
}
```

Error:

> 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `.DataSources`

**Replace:**

```
rptInventoryStock.LocalReport.Add(new ReportDataSource("IOOP_DatabaseDataSet", dtbl));
```

**With**

```
rptInventoryStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("IOOP_DatabaseDataSet", dtbl));
```